# Retrieve user's email in twitter -react native

Tags: twitter, react-native, twitter-oauth

I've used [react-native-twitter-signin](https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin/blob/master/README.md) lib to login through twitter. It works well but doesn't give user's email. It is mentioned that you have to apply for a permission for your app to retrieve user's email

How can I ask for a permission to make it work?

Code:

```
const Constants = {
    TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY: 'XXXXXXX',
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
};

export default class twitterLogin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
        }
        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
    }

    _twitterSignIn() {
        RNTwitterSignIn.init(Constants.TWITTER_COMSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        RNTwitterSignIn.logIn()
            .then((loginData)=>{
                console.log(loginData);
                const { authToken, authTokenSecret } = loginData;
                if (authToken && authTokenSecret) {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoggedIn: true,
                    });
                }
            }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    handleLogout() {
        console.log('logout');
        RNTwitterSignIn.logOut();
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: false,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {
                isLoggedIn
                    ?
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.handleLogout}
                    >
                        <Text>Log out</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    :
                    <Icon.Button name='logo-twitter' size={32} color='white' style={styles.icon} onPress={this._twitterSignIn.bind(this)}>
                        Login with Twitter
                    </Icon.Button>
            }
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: According to twitter API "When set to true email will be returned in the user objects as a string. If the user does not have an email address on their account, or if the email address is not verified, null will be returned." On the modules true is set so if an email is present and verified it should be returned. I think what he means by apply for permissions is that the user must confirmed email access during the login processus.

Answer (score 0):

In your permission tab => 'Request email addresses from users' check
and enter 'Privacy Policy URL' & 'Terms of Service URL' it will give user email